# Create custom templates in iOS ap

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

How to create custom templates in iOS app having uiimageview ,uitextview,and many other views so that user can select any one template and starts editing it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a famous library thats floating around for this kind of usage - [iOS BoilerPlate](http://iosboilerplate.com/)

- It is intended to provide a base of code to start with
- It is not intended to be a framework
- It is intended to be modified and extended by the developer to fit their needs
- It includes solid third-party libraries if needed to not reinvent the wheel

What it includes -

- HTTP requests and an image cache (both in-memory and disk-based)
- UITableViews and UITableViewCells: fast scrolling, async images, pull-down-to-refresh, swipeable cells,...
- A built-in browser so your users don't leave your application when they browse to a certain URL
- Maps and locations: directions between two points, autocomplete a location, etc.